# What demosaic algorithm is best for DNG to B&W conversion?

Tags: raw, dng, algorithms, bayer, demosaicing

I figure that at some point someone has devised a demosaic algorithm that is optimal for converting a Bayer DNG to a B&W photograph. But what is that algorithm called, and what image processing software offers it?

dcraw has a "document mode" that has surprisingly good results but it doesn't merge pixels... there is no demosaicing.

Answer (score 2):

> I figure that at some point someone has devised a demosaic algorithm that is optimal for converting a Bayer DNG to a B&W photograph.

Well "optimal" is in the eye of the beholder.

Your idea of an optimal conversion may not be my idea of an optimal conversion.  So on this notion the idea of an optimal conversion flounders.

On a fundamental level, demoisaicing algorithms are concerned with generating RGB images from RAW data.

And B&W image processing, even in the days of film, involved color filtering.

With film you actually did use a physical filter when you shot in order to get different contrast effects for different colors.  In digital, normally, you'd work from a color image and apply a filter of choice (or any other processing) to get the effect you want.

The point is that B&W processing is almost entirely something you do now from a color base image (implicit even if you shoot RAW).

Even if you attempt to do this from RAW, you must construct an implicit full color image in order to apply a color filter-type of effect (something I'd regard as pretty much essential for serious B&W work).  A color filter, by definition, requires a color source image.

The only alternative is rarely done these days with digital - shooting with a physical color filter.

> But what is that algorithm called, and what image processing software offers it?

There is no single algorithm that would be universally considered optimal, but I can't say I've heard of an algorithm specifically designed to facilitate only B&W work.  As I've explained, it's a self defeating idea to not work from a base color image these days.

Comment: But if a conversion is first done to color (RGB) and then to B&W the emphasis will initially making the color look "good", which may adversely affect the luminosity. Surely there is a way to avoid the sometimes elaborate operations that companies use to adapt Bayer patterns to different types of scenes and whatnot.

Comment: No.  The emphasis is not on making the color "look good", but to be as accurate as possible with respect to the color response of the sensor.  "Looking good" is for secondary effects, like saturation, white balance, tone, sharpening, contrast, tone curve.  RGB demosaicing is a necessity for generating good luminosity data.

Comment: Have you done much reading about how demosaicing works? There are several ways to do it. Some look really bad, some look better. It depends on the scene type. So I am correct, the demosaicing method is chosen to make the photo look good. And the choice usually takes color into account which does not apply in the case of a B&W photo.

Comment: Yes, I am quite familiar with demoisaicing algorithms.  They are not chosen "to make the photo look good", they are generally chosen to minimize artifacts of interpolation, something that very careful expert evaluation of the algorithms decides.  "Looking good" is a subjective quality of an image viewed as a complete composition, not at the pixel level of demosaicing.

Comment: I think you're straining to try to appear right or knowledgable here. An artifact by definition does not look correct. It's not in accord with the objective facts of a scene. A demoisaicing algorithm is chosen to minimize those in order to look good i.e. good meaning objectively correct.

Comment: An artifact can look perfectly correct visually.  I have no idea why you think it's a definition that it should somehow stand out.  An artifact means, in this context, a very fine detail that does not accurately represent the reality.  However that does not mean it would be at all obvious that something is an artifact and not perfectly reasonable data within the accuracy of the sensor.

Comment: Most every B&W image, film or digital, begins with a scene that has color. Once recorded as a monochromatic image (whether via silver halide or JPEG) that color information is lost. Even though each pixel has only a single luminance value in the raw data captured by a sensor, every image captured with a Bayer masked sensor also has color information embedded in it via the varying tonal values resulting from filtering the same colors by red, green, and blue. To get any meaningful image that remotely represents the reality of the scene the raw data from a Bayer masked sensor must be demosaiced.

Comment: Even if the scene recorded is already monochromatic, the varying responses yielded by the R, G, & B filters will yield different tonal values unless the light entering the camera is *perfectly* balanced to produce the same response in the R, G, & B filtered pixels, respectively. That *might* be theoretically possible depending on the sensor's response curves, but in the real world would be near impossible to actually achieve outside a carefully controlled laboratory environment.

Comment: @iSelfy "...But if a conversion is first done to color (RGB) and then to B&W the emphasis will initially making the color look "good", which may adversely affect the luminosity." The instant you capture the scene with a Bayer masked sensor the full luminosity has already been irretrievably lost to the light absorbed and reflected by the Bayer mask.